# how to show search product's image?

Tags: search

buddy:
I want to know how to modify the code that can show product's image when i search products?
Like this!
[image]

Thank you very for your help!

Comment: What is version of Magento you use?

Comment: This site's vesion is 1.9.3, But i want to develop a new magento 2.0 vesion site, so i want to konw the two vesion's method! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a third party modul (autocomplete). I use smart search for my mag 1.9.3 . For Magento 2.0 you will find also a modul for this in the marketplace.

Comment: Yes, i have search it via google , but i didn't found ! I cantact the magento system is not  a very long time, so i need to more study!

Comment: Here you find a couple of modules: https://marketplace.magento.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=autocomplete#q=autocomplete&idx=m2_cloud_prod_default_products&p=0&fR%5Bext_compatible_versions%5D%5B0%5D=1.9.3&nR%5Bvisibility_search%5D%5B%3D%5D%5B0%5D=1&is_v=1

Comment: I want to myself develop it, maybe it a more better idea!